# mix run terminates my programs

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, elixir-mix

Been struggling wrapping my head around this and hoping someone would be able to point me in the right direction.

I ran `mix new my_other_app --sup` and got the bellow application:

```
defmodule MyOtherApp do

  def start_link do
    Task.start_link(fn -> loop() end)
  end

  def loop do
    IO.puts "running..."
    :timer.sleep(1000)
    loop()
  end
end
```

And my application supervisor:

```
defmodule MyOtherApp.Application do
  use Application

  def start(_type, _args) do
    import Supervisor.Spec, warn: false

    children = [
      worker(MyOtherApp, [])
    ]

    opts = [strategy: :one_for_one, name: MyOtherApp.Supervisor]
    Supervisor.start_link(children, opts)
  end
end
```

and mix `application/0`

```
def application do
  [extra_applications: [:logger],
   mod: {MyOtherApp.Application, []}]
end
```

Now my questions are:

- Why is it that when I run `mix app.start`, the application runs and halts straight away?
- When would I run `mix app.start` instead of `mix run`?
- I know that I can do `mix run --no-halt` to get the application continue running forever, but why? Why is it that if I remove the supervisor and put a call to `loop/0` at the bottom of my `my_other_app.ex`, it continues running forever with `mix run` but with the supervisor it doesn't?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Usually `mix run` is used to run a file (*.exs).
_Before running any command, the task compiles and starts the current application._

Keep in mind that starting an application also starts it's applications.
`mix app.start` starts all registered applications. I think this means, it's starting all applications except the main application.

Answer (score 1):

The issue seems to be related to how I was calling the `loop/0` function within a task process that wasn't being supervised.

Pretty simple but the process of writing this helped me get there ;)

Thanks for the rubber ducking, SO ;)

EDIT: I will still mark right answer to someone who can explain to me when I'd run `mix run` vs `mix app.start`

Thanks